# How to delete a class that starts with the same pattern using JQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, shiny

I have to delete the part of HTML code of the following basic specification using JQuery Selector:

```
 <i class="fa fa-hotel bg-olive"></i>
```

There are several code lines that has to be deleted. The have all have class values that starts with "fa fa-". These class type stays for the special icons. So, I want to match by the class that starts from "fa fa-" and than delete the lines with the button.

I tried something like `[class*='fa fa']` and `[class^='fa fa']` for Selector, but it did not worked.

However I can delete the lines if I do something like `.fa fa-hotel`. 
Since I have too many class variations, I do not want to do it like statement by statement for each separate class.

**Update:** I work with R Shiny Framework to accomplish this task. The whole code looks like this:

```
  observeEvent(input$deleteButton_timeline, {
    removeUI(selector ="[class^='fa fa']")
  })
```

Comment: `[class^='fa fa']` should work, what exactly did you try?

Comment: @ billyonecan I tried [class^='fa fa'] but it did not worked some how. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: where's the rest of your code? that alone isn't going to do anything since it's just a string, presumably you tried something like `$('[class^="fa fa"]').remove();`? you need to include the code you tried in your question otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: @billyonecan I do not do it directly via JS but in R Shiny Framework. There is a module called `removeUI` that  does all the work: `removeUI(selector ="[class^='fa fa']")`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```js
var classes = $("i").attr("class");
console.log(classes);


if ($("i").attr("class").indexOf("fa fa-") >= 0){
console.log(true);
$("i").removeClass("fa");
//removes fa
$("i").removeClass(function (index, css) {
  return (css.match (/\bfa\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
});
//removes classes starting with fa
}



if ($("i").attr("class").indexOf("fa fa-") >= 0){
console.log(true);
}else{
var classes = $("i").attr("class");
console.log(classes);
console.log(false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-hotel bg-olive"></i>
```